# how to get the values in array and how to insert in database using codeiniter

Tags: php, json, codeigniter, model

Here i have one array, in this array i have one more array name `studentAbsentId`, now i want insert the `studentAbsentId` in database, like here `studentAbsentId` 2 and `studentAbsentId` 2 is absent so i need to insert the two rows

> My updated code      **print_r($params);**

```
 Array
(
    [studentAbsentId] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2
            [1] => 3
        )

    [schoolId] => 2
    [classId] => 1
    [sectionId] => 1
    [studentAbsentDate] => 2017-04-18
    [reg_date] => 2017-04-18 05:20:17
    [created_by] => 1
)
```

Now i want to take only studentAbsentId,how can do?

> expected results

```
2

3
```

Comment: so what happened when you run this code? do you see any error? describe and mention your problem

Comment: please check my updated code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this it helps :)

```
<?php

$params=array(
        'studentAbsentId' => array
            ( 2,3
            ),
        'studentAbsentDate' => '2017-04-18',
        'reg_date' => '2017-04-18 04:41:21',
        'created_by' => '1',
    );


foreach($params['studentAbsentId'] as $ff)
{
        $atnEntry = array(
        "studentAbsentId" => $ff,
        "studentAbsentDate" =>$params['studentAbsentDate'],
        "morning" => "1"

        );

        $this->db->insert("student_absent_list" , $atnEntry);
}        
        $return = array("status" => "Success" );
        echo json_encode($return);  

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$test = array('studentAbsentId' => array('2','3'),'studentAbsentDate' => '2017-04-18','reg_date' => '2017-04-18 04:41:21','created_by' => '1');

    foreach($test['studentAbsentId'] AS $tet)
    {
        $array_val = array('studentAbsentId' => $tet,'studentAbsentDate' => $test['studentAbsentDate'],'created_by' => $test['created_by']);

        // echo "<pre>";print_r($array_val);

        $this->db->insert('table_name',$array_val);
    }
```